# Using Yii2 Query Builder, how do you set null values to empty strings?

Tags: yii, yii2

I would like Yii2's Query Builder to return empty strings for null values.

The equivalent of this:

```
IFNULL(Table.Column1, '')
```

In this:

```
$rows = (new \yii\db\Query())
->select(['Column1', 'Column2'])
->from('Table')
->all();
```

Comment: Please try the suggested answers and then mark them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this way

You can specify columns to be selected in either an array or a string, like the following.  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-query.html#select()-detail

```
$rows = (new \yii\db\Query())
   ->select([" IFNULL(Column1,''),  Column2  "])
   ->from('Table')
   ->all();
```

or

```
$rows = (new \yii\db\Query())
   ->select([" IFNULL(Column1,'')",  Column2])
   ->from('Table')
   ->all();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$rows = (new \yii\db\Query())
->select(['Column1'=>'IFNULL(Column1,''), 'Column2'])
->from('Table')
->all();
```